# Push items to associative array individually in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a snippet like,

Assume different length of array like,

length of `$name1Array` is 8 and length of `$name2Array` is 5

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count ( $name1Array ); $i ++)
    {
        $finalArray ["something"] [] = array (
                "name1" => $name1Array [$i],
                "name2" => $name2Array [$i] 
        );

    }
```

The above snippet is working all fine, but when the lengths of $name1Array and $name2Array are different? I tried 2 for loops for each one like,

```
for($i = 0; $i < count ( $name1Array ); $i ++)
    {
        $finalArray ["something"] [] = array (
                "name1" => $name1Array [$i]

        );

    }

for($i = 0; $i < count ( $name2Array ); $i ++)
    {
        $finalArray ["something"] [] = array (
                "name2" => $name2Array [$i]

        );

    }
```

This didnt work, is there any work around for it?

Comment: Change the keyname "something" to anything else for maintaining both arrays, or show your expected result

Comment: @Mann Please clarify your question by including some sample data that causes your issue and then state your exact expected output from the sample input.  This makes your question more clear and improves your chances of receiving a high quality solution.

Comment: @Mann do you want to store null values when one array has run out of values -- to preserve the origin of the data?

Answer (score 0):

One Of sollition is to
Find Max Count value from both array and loop till max array val.

```
<?php

$array1 = array("a","b","c","d");
$array2 = array("1","2","3","4","5");

$count1 = count ( $array1 );$count2 = count ( $array2 );
$looptill = max($count1,$count2);

for($i = 0; $i < $looptill ; $i ++)
    {
        $finalArray ["something"] [] = array (
                "name1" => $array1 [$i],
                "name2" => $array2 [$i] 
        );

    }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalArray);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your expected result should be, so I'm guessing here that you want the longest possible result by filling missing values with `null` or another *empty value*.

Try this:

```
$c1 = count($name1Array);
$c2 = count($name2Array);
$cmax = max($c1, $c2);

for ($i = 0; $i < $cmax; $i++)
{
    $finalArray["something"][] = [
        "name1" => $i < $c1 ? $name1Array[$i] : null,
        "name2" => $i < $c2 ? $name2Array[$i] : null
    ];
}
```

As an alternative, you may want the shortest result by omitting those that are not present in both arrays:

```
$c1 = count($name1Array);
$c2 = count($name2Array);
$cmin = min($c1, $c2);

for ($i = 0; $i < $cmin; $i++)
{
    $finalArray["something"][] = [
        "name1" => $name1Array[$i],
        "name2" => $name2Array[$i]
    ];
}
```

The fact that you didn't specify which of the two (longest/shortest) versions you need is an indication that you didn't think the problem through and probably are doing just homework... anyways, you're just hurting yourself this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to push `null` elements where missing from the original arrays, `array_map()` is a direct one-liner:

```
$array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
$array2 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');

$finalArray['something'] = array_map(function($v1, $v2){return ['name1' => $v1, 'name2' => $v2];}, $array1, $array2);
var_export($finalArray);
```

*`array_map()` does you the favor of serving `null` values when the input array is expired.

If you don't want to see any `null` values, a `for()` loop is probably a better choice:

```
for ($i = 0, $max = max(sizeof($array1), sizeof($array2)); $i < $max; ++$i) {
    $tmp = [];
    if (isset($array1[$i])) {            // this condition is important to avoid Notices
        $tmp['name1'] = $array1[$i];
    }
    if (isset($array2[$i])) {            // this condition is important to avoid Notices
        $tmp['name2'] = $array2[$i];
    }
    $final['something'][] = $tmp;
}
var_export($final);
```

[Here is a demonstration.](https://3v4l.org/1NldY)