# php build array/json object structure

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

Trying to achieve this structure of jsondata based on an API I am trying to connect to:

```
{
    "VoucherDate": "2019-10-27",
    "VoucherText": "string",
    "VoucherType": 2,
    "Rows": [{
            "AccountNumber": 0,
            "DebitAmount": 0,
            "CreditAmount": 0,
            "TransactionText": "string"
        },
        {
            "AccountNumber": 0,
            "DebitAmount": 0,
            "CreditAmount": 0,
            "TransactionText": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

The code I have experimented with so far, below, generates this structure. The Rows array doesn't get the same structure as above, where do I do wrong?

```
{
    "VoucherDate": "2019-10-31",
    "VoucherText": "string",
    "VoucherType": 2,
    "Rows": [{
        "TransactionText": "test"
    }, {
        "AccountNumber": 1000
    }, {
        "DebitAmount": 1
    }, {
        "CreditAMount": 2
    }, {
        "TransactionText": "test"
    }, {
        "AccountNumber": 1000
    }, {
        "DebitAmount": 1
    }, {
        "CreditAMount": 2
    }]
}
```

Php code:

```
$postdata = array();
$postdata["VoucherDate"] = "2019-10-31";
$postdata["VoucherText"] = "string";
$postdata["VoucherType"] = 2; 
$postdata["Rows"] = array();

for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
    $postdata["Rows"][]["TransactionText"] = "string";
    $postdata["Rows"][]["AccountNumber"] = 0;
    $postdata["Rows"][]["DebitAmount"] = 0;
    $postdata["Rows"][]["CreditAMount"] = ;

}   

echo json_encode($postdata);
```

Comment: Each time you are calling `arr[]`, you are creating a new element. You should add them all to an array and then create 1 new element for it as @NigelRen suggested below.

Comment: No upvotes on this page, so can't add to the dupe list: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51354958/2943403

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/q/16308252/2943403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add all of the elements into one array before adding them to your overall data, something like....

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
    $postdata["Rows"][] = ["TransactionText" => "string", 
                           "AccountNumber" => 0,
                           "DebitAmount" => 0,
                           "CreditAMount" = 2];

}
```